# CSS file isn't applying to the page, not loading under sources

Tags: html, css, django

I was trying to link a css file to my html, and for some reason the css won't load in. Below I'll supply the html and css code. When I open the page source, the css href works fine, I can click on it and it takes me to the css file, but when I inspect I can see that the css file is not part of sources. I've tested my code on JSFiddle and it works fine there, as well as on the snippet here. I also tried pressing ctrl + f5 and shift + f5 to refresh the page without caches, but nothing changed. So I don't know what else to do to fix this. I've been doing it on Chrome so I tested it real quick on Firefox but still, no changes. Thanks in advance for any help.

raw html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="'stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<header>
    <div class="site-header" width="100%" height="100px">
        <h3><a class="site-header-link" href="/polls">Home</a></h3>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Runnable html and css.

```css
li a {
    color: green;
}

body {
    background: grey;
}

.question-display {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    position: center;
}

.question-link {
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

.choices {

}

.question-container {

}

.site-header {
    color: aqua;
}

.site-header-link {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="'stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/styles.css">
</head>
<header>
    <div class="site-header" width="100%" height="100px">
        <h3><a class="site-header-link" href="/polls">Home</a></h3>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
    
    
        
            <div class="question-display">
                <ln><a class="question-link" target="_blank" href="3/">What&#x27;s your favorite game?</a></ln>
            </div>
        
            <div class="question-display">
                <ln><a class="question-link" target="_blank" href="2/">How are you?</a></ln>
            </div>
        
            <div class="question-display">
                <ln><a class="question-link" target="_blank" href="1/">What&#x27;s up?</a></ln>
            </div>
        
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an additional quote in the rel= property. It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/styles.css' %}">
```

Comment: Oh my lord, I can't believe that was the problem xD. Damn, I wish I'd noticed that myself, either way, thank you for your keen eyes.